# Como SELECT en segundo Rank de Top

Tags: sql-server

Quiero hacer esto:

Mil corredores corren una carrera, toman la mayor cantidad de palos, el ganador es el del primer lugar es Juan con 200000, segundo lugar pedro con 50 y el tercer lugar pedro con 2 palitos. Debo hacer select por nombre Pedro que solo se vea el segundo lugar de la recogida de palitos.

NO, esto no lo quiero ya que pedro puede ser cualquiera, es una variable, lo importante son los palitos recogidos en valor BIGINT.

```
SELECT nombre FROM TABLE Where Nombre PEDRO

SELECT TOP 1 nombre FROM TABLE 
SELECT TOP 2 nombre FROM TABLE 
SELECT TOP 3 nombre FROM TABLE
```

Quiero que el Excel, me muestre el que segundo que recogió más palitos, el tercero, pero solo si hago Pedro que es el segundo lugar me muestre solo a Pedro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es mas fácil con datos reales y estructura de tablas reales, pero bueno, suponiendo que tienes una tabla tablaPosiciones con las columnas nombre y cantPalitos:

```
 --1ro
 SELECT TOP 1 NOMBRE, cantPalitos FROM tablaPosiciones ORDER BY cantPalitos DESC

 --2do
 SELECT NOMBRE, cantPalitos FROM tablaPosiciones  WHERE cantPalitos = (
 SELECT TOP 2 MIN(cantPalitos) FROM tablaPosiciones ORDER BY cantPalitos DESC)

 --3ro
 SELECT NOMBRE, cantPalitos FROM tablaPosiciones  WHERE cantPalitos = (
 SELECT TOP 3 MIN(cantPalitos) FROM tablaPosiciones ORDER BY cantPalitos DESC)
```

Comment: Olvidé comentar que en caso de empate en el 2do  o 3er lugar te devolverá 2 registros, tendríamos que ver que querrías hacer en ese caso

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes obtener con una subconsulta y la función ROW_NUMBER de la siguiente forma

```
select subconsulta.Nombre 
from (select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by NumeroPalos desc) id,Nombre
from TABLE) as subconsulta
Where id = 2
```

Suponiendo que la columna "NumeroPalos" es la cantidad de palos tomados, los ordenas de forma descendente y al momento de llamar a la subconsulta le aplicas un where que selecciona en el orden numero 2 que sera el segundo que tomo mas palos

Lo que hace la función ROW_NUMBER es enumerar las datos seleccionados en el orden o partición que tu le indiques

Answer (score 0):

en este caso te recomiendo usar un sp, es mas sencillo pero si lo que requieres es un query usa el siguiente:

```
select subconsulta.Nombre 
from (select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by NumeroPalos desc) id,Nombre
from [tabla1]) as subconsulta
Where id = 2
UNION
select subconsulta3.Nombre 
from (select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by NumeroPalos desc) id,Nombre,NumeroPalos
from [tabla1]) as subconsulta2 
INNER JOIN 
(select ROW_NUMBER() over(order BY NumeroPalos desc) id,Nombre,NumeroPalos
from [tabla1]) as subconsulta3 ON subconsulta3.NumeroPalos = subconsulta2.NumeroPalos 
and subconsulta2.id =2 AND subconsulta3.id =3
```